# Blender 3.1 Shadow Problems with "Hair" Simulation

Tags: gpu, shadows

I just recently updated my Blender version to 3.1 from 2.9. I wanted to render out a scene I have had, but I noticed many of the cubes are pitch black. I know they have to do with shadows from playing around with settings. I have tried subdivided the meshes, and I have recalculated all the normals. I have an image of this problem.[image: Many of the blocks are black. They return to normal if I remove shadows.]
Many of the blocks are black. They return to normal when I remove shadows.

I am using Cycles with Cuda. I am using a Geforce GTX 1060 3GB. Note that when I change the device to CPU the glitch disappears.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the hair simulation, I found that I was using too many objects in my scene. I had the hair count to 5000 when the amount needed was only 4225.